# Enable cells with button click in selected row windows form application c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` where the rows are adding dynamically with a button click. And the cells of those rows are `ReadOnly`. I want those cells to be clickable with a button click when i select a specific row. That means the cells of selected row should be clickable. Is it possible to do? If so can i get an example?

```
int currentColumCount = Int32.Parse(addModule.numberOfAssessmentsMaskedTextBox.Text);
for (int i = assessmentDataTableOnFour.Columns.Count - 1; i < currentColumCount; i++)
{
    DataColumn column = assessmentDataTableOnFour.Columns.Add("Assesment " + (i + 1));
    assessmentDataGridViewOnFour.ReadOnly = true;
}
addAssessmentButtonOnFour.Enabled = true;
assessmentDataTableOnFour.Rows.Add(new string[] 
{
    addModule.ModuleNameTextBox.Text + " : " + addModule.ModuleCodeTextBox.Text + " : " + addModule.ModuleCreditsTextBox.Text + " credits"
});


private void addAssessmentButtonClickedOnFour(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in assessmentDataGridViewOnFour.SelectedRows)
    {
        assessmentDataGridViewOnFour.ReadOnly = false;
        assessmentDataGridViewOnFour.Columns["Module Details"].ReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: is this asp.net? show your code

Comment: windows form application

Comment: You mean you just need to be able to select them?

Comment: row.Cells[0].ReadOnly = false; for the selected row pass current cell index this should help let me know

Comment: @BugFinder - yhh once i select a row and click a button the cells of that particular row should be writable.

Comment: @Harry - where to put that code. in the button click event?

Comment: please update your question, and format the code

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Is it not possible to use the CellClick event handler? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i'm using cell click event handler to pop up a form